# Capturar evento de click no play do youtube

Tags: html5, youtube, vídeo

Tenho uma section responsiva com um vídeo do youtube, gostaria de capturar o evento do click no play do vídeo do youtube, teria como capturar? ou seja, mandar um alert por exemplo, assim que for dado o play no vídeo do youtube.

Comment: Arnaldo, poderia postar o trecho do código para que possamos ajuda-lo?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a API Javascript do YouTube (https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?hl=pt-br)

Utilizando o callback `onStateChange`, você pega qual é o tipo de status do vídeo.

> Eventos
>
> onStateChange
>       Esse evento é disparado sempre que o estado do player for alterado. O valor que a API passa para sua função de listener de
>   eventos especificará um número inteiro que corresponde ao novo estado
>   do player. Os valores possíveis são:
>
> ```
>     -1 (não iniciado)
>     0 (encerrado)
>     1 (em reprodução)
>     2 (em pausa)
>     3 (armazenando em buffer)
>     5 (vídeo indicado).
> ```
>
> Quando o player carrega um vídeo pela primeira vez, ele transmite um evento não iniciado unstarted (-1). Quando o vídeo estiver indicado
>   e pronto para ser reproduzido, o player transmitirá um evento de vídeo
>   indicado video cued (5). Em seu código, você pode especificar valores
>   de números inteiros ou pode usar uma das seguintes variáveis
>   namespaced:
>
> ```
>     YT.PlayerState.ENDED
>     YT.PlayerState.PLAYING
>     YT.PlayerState.PAUSED
>     YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING
>     YT.PlayerState.CUED
> ```